# get 100 latitude and longitudes around selected location within radius of 100 m

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on a location based Android application. It uses Google Maps. Currently When I click on the map it drops the pin on map and I get lat and long of that location. But Now I need a list of about 100 more lat and long around selected location within radius of 100 meters. can any one suggest me how can I get multiple lat and long around the location
Thank you

Comment: Just make a loop which you execute a thousand times. Add a very small value to lat or long or both. If you took the value very small you could even generate a million points within 100 metres.

Comment: @greenapps I need lat longs exactly in  a radius of 100 meters circle. How can I restrict that? And it should cover the circle fully.

Comment: Do you need them on the radius or within the radius.  Those are two different requirements

Comment: How should 100 points cover a circle fully?

Comment: @GabeSechan within radius

Comment: @greenapps for each location i will be giving some radius for ex if I give a radius of 1 meter for every pin it will cover 100 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe formula for length of 1 degree lat/long is

```
m1 = 111132.92;     // latitude calculation term 1
m2 = -559.82;       // latitude calculation term 2
m3 = 1.175;         // latitude calculation term 3
m4 = -0.0023;       // latitude calculation term 4
p1 = 111412.84;     // longitude calculation term 1
p2 = -93.5;         // longitude calculation term 2
p3 = 0.118;         // longitude calculation term 3

// Calculate the length of a degree of latitude and longitude in meters
latlen = m1 + (m2 * Math.cos(2 * lat)) + (m3 * Math.cos(4 * lat)) +
        (m4 * Math.cos(6 * lat));
longlen = (p1 * Math.cos(lat)) + (p2 * Math.cos(3 * lat)) +
            (p3 * Math.cos(5 * lat));
```

To get the number of degrees in 1 meter, invert that (divide 1 by the longlen and latlen).

The formula for a circle is x^2+y^2=radius^2.  So you can pick a random value [-100,100] for the x, and from [-radius^2-x^2,radius^2-x^2] for the y.  Then convert x into degrees latitude and y into degrees longitude using the conversion factors above.  Then add those amounts to the center point.  That will give you a random location within radius meters of the center